# What should happen to the data when disabling an app in django?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, cascade

I have a django app "my_debug" that contains a model like this:

```py
class MyDebugEntry(Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    data = TextField()
```

This app is only for debugging purposes, so I add it to `INSTALLED_APPS` when I need it and remove it afterwards. This works fine for the most part.

However, when I try to remove a user I get the following error message:

```
IntegrityError at /some/path/
update or delete on table "auth_users" violates foreign key constraint "mydebug_mydebugentry_user_id_d738bc03_fk_users_" on table "mydebug_mydebugentry"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(5) is still referenced from table "mydebug_mydebugentry".
```

This is because [`on_delete=CASCADE` is implemented in python](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete), not in the database itself. So when the "my_debug" app is disabled, the `on_deleted` behavior is disabled along with it.

So what is the proper way to do this? Should I drop all of the app's tables when removing it from `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: I'd have probably migrated the app into non-existence first. Delete its model definitions, create the migration, apply it. There should then be nothing left over to prevent un-installation of the app. If there are DB constraints making this process less than straightforward, doing it this way should reveal them and point towards the solutions. I don't know whether this actually deletes the DB tables or just leaves them empty of content. I've never done this (yet).

Comment: But how would I provide that migration? AFAIK django does not have a mechaism for "run this migration from this app only if the app is not installed".

Comment: I meant, before you un-installed the app. You might be able to re-install it just by adding it back to INSTALLED_APPS, if all the DB tables are still there.